# Sort symbol index by page occurence

Tags: indexing, sorting

SE, I have a problem ordering items in symbol index. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\let\memoldbibsection\bibsection
\let\bibsection\relax
%\usepackage[nobysame]{amsrefs}
\let\bibsection\memoldbibsection 

\usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}


\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc, name=sym,title=Symbol index]

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae laoreet eros. Nam dapibus ante nec suscipit mattis. Mauris tempus tortor nunc, sed suscipit neque varius vel. Duis semper elit libero, a porttitor tellus vehicula id. Maecenas semper lacinia lectus, et tempor mauris pulvinar vel. Vivamus placerat ipsum enim, sit amet dignissim purus placerat nec. Suspendisse mattis ipsum convallis bibendum mattis. Nullam gravida eros vitae enim aliquam venenatis. Duis faucibus tincidunt velit, id eleifend mauris fermentum malesuada. Nunc blandit metus turpis, nec auctor elit tristique non. Proin ut mattis elit. Nam ac nulla sodales, ullamcorper lacus porta, eleifend urna. Maecenas eget dui vitae turpis pulvinar auctor. Maecenas a porttitor dolor.

%Multiple times Lorem Ipsum so that symbols end up in different pages

\index[sym]{$(E, \mathcal{E})$}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae laoreet eros. Nam dapibus ante nec suscipit mattis. Mauris tempus tortor nunc, sed suscipit neque varius vel. Duis semper elit libero, a porttitor tellus vehicula id. Maecenas semper lacinia lectus, et tempor mauris pulvinar vel. Vivamus placerat ipsum enim, sit amet dignissim purus placerat nec. Suspendisse mattis ipsum convallis bibendum mattis. Nullam gravida eros vitae enim aliquam venenatis. Duis faucibus tincidunt velit, id eleifend mauris fermentum malesuada. Nunc blandit metus turpis, nec auctor elit tristique non. Proin ut mattis elit. Nam ac nulla sodales, ullamcorper lacus porta, eleifend urna. Maecenas eget dui vitae turpis pulvinar auctor. Maecenas a porttitor dolor.

\index[sym]{$abc$}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae laoreet eros. Nam dapibus ante nec suscipit mattis. Mauris tempus tortor nunc, sed suscipit neque varius vel. Duis semper elit libero, a porttitor tellus vehicula id. Maecenas semper lacinia lectus, et tempor mauris pulvinar vel. Vivamus placerat ipsum enim, sit amet dignissim purus placerat nec. Suspendisse mattis ipsum convallis bibendum mattis. Nullam gravida eros vitae enim aliquam venenatis. Duis faucibus tincidunt velit, id eleifend mauris fermentum malesuada. Nunc blandit metus turpis, nec auctor elit tristique non. Proin ut mattis elit. Nam ac nulla sodales, ullamcorper lacus porta, eleifend urna. Maecenas eget dui vitae turpis pulvinar auctor. Maecenas a porttitor dolor.

%Multiple times Lorem Ipsum so that symbols end up in different pages

\index[sym]{$\mu_{X}$}

\index[sym]{$\mu_{Y}$}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae laoreet eros. Nam dapibus ante nec suscipit mattis. Mauris tempus tortor nunc, sed suscipit neque varius vel. Duis semper elit libero, a porttitor tellus vehicula id. Maecenas semper lacinia lectus, et tempor mauris pulvinar vel. Vivamus placerat ipsum enim, sit amet dignissim purus placerat nec. Suspendisse mattis ipsum convallis bibendum mattis. Nullam gravida eros vitae enim aliquam venenatis. Duis faucibus tincidunt velit, id eleifend mauris fermentum malesuada. Nunc blandit metus turpis, nec auctor elit tristique non. Proin ut mattis elit. Nam ac nulla sodales, ullamcorper lacus porta, eleifend urna. Maecenas eget dui vitae turpis pulvinar auctor. Maecenas a porttitor dolor.

\clearpage
\chaptermark{Symbol index}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Symbol index}
\printindex[sym]


\end{document}
```

Now as you will see by running this example the order in index does not reflect the order of occurence of the symbols.

How do I force index to be ordered by the number of page where the symbol first occured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can record an auxiliary counter as the sorting part. This assumes you have less than 1000 symbols (but it can be extended if needed).

In order to cope with multiple occurrences, the first one will set a key.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc, name=sym,title=Symbol index]

\newcounter{indexcount}
\newcommand{\threedigit}[1]{\ifnum #1<100 0\fi\ifnum #1<10 0\fi#1}

\newcommand{\symindex}[1]{%
  \ifcsname\detokenize{SYM@@#1}\endcsname
    \index[sym]{\csname\detokenize{SYM@@#1}\endcsname @#1}%
  \else
    \stepcounter{indexcount}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname SYM@@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname{%
      \expandafter\threedigit\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q\theindexcount}%
    }%
    \index[sym]{\threedigit{\theindexcount}@\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Some text

% The following two symbols are at page 1
\symindex{$(E, \mathcal{E})$}
\symindex{$abc$}
\symindex{$abc$}

\clearpage

Some text

% this is at page 2
\symindex{$\mu_{X}$}
\symindex{$(E, \mathcal{E})$}

\clearpage

Some text

% this is at page 3
\symindex{$\mu_{Y}$}

\printindex[sym]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this would be more compelling if the example showed multiple page numbers for a particular symbol.  as i understand the question, a symbol can be listed as occurring in multiple places, but the sort order should be by the page number of the first occurrence; it would probably be nice if symbols on the "first" page were in the same order in which they actually appear on that page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the remarks; it turns out that recording the page number is actually not needed. Anyway, symbols *were* in the order of appearance in the page also in the previous version.

Comment: Awsome! This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg I noticed that when I use your construction some in particular $\langle$ is rendered as hA and $\rangle$ as B. Do you know what might cause that? Before it rendered as one would expect.

Comment: @data Fixed. One needs a couple of `\unexpanded` tokens around `#1`

Comment: how about replacing `\threedigits` by `\the\numexpr1000000000+#1\relax` ? then you can have lots of symbols :)

Comment: @jfbu That's a good idea.

Comment: @egreg, how can you modify `symindex` so that it does not typeset the argument in place? All that expand-fu is beyond my powers to modify it :-|

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Does it? I don't think so.

Comment: Currently `symindex{$1+1$}` typesets the $1+1$ and adds the index entry.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Not this code. Did you perhaps modify it?